How to access the ar.js camera feed in order to take a snapshot?
I'm trying to take a snapshot of the camera feed in order to scan QR codes in my application.
I've tried to inspect the data using the code below, but I can't find a way to access the media stream.
window.addEventListener('camera-init', (data) => {
            console.log(data );
    })

